# Checking a hash for the existence of a matching value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm building a school calendar that lists classes ("sections") and displays semester and exam dates for those classes. The calendar is fed a hash that is defined in the `Section.rb` model:

```
  def get_calendar

    calendar = {}
    calendar[:semesters] = Semester.where(section_id: self.id)
    calendar[:exams] = Exam.where(section_id: self.id)

    { :calendar => calendar }

  end
```

The `Semester` and `Exam` objects have a `name`, `start_date` and `end_date`.

**When looping through each day of the calendar, how can I check if there's a semester or exam with a** `start_date` **or** `end_date` **for that day of the loop?**

If there is a semester or exam with either a `start_date` or `end_date` that matches the calendar date, I would to display the name.

The calendar dates and the `start_date` and `end_date` fields all use the `Date` class ([link](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)).

I sincerely appreciate the help. I can clarify the question if needed :)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example illustrating what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should re-think your hash, and use it this way:

```
def get_calendar
  semesters = self.semesters
  exams = self.exams

  events = { }

  (semesters + exams).each do |event|
    start_date = event.start_date.to_s
    events[start_date] ||= []
    events[start_date] << event

    end_date = event.end_date.to_s
    events[end_date] ||= []
    events[end_date] << event
  end

  events
end
```

And test the presence of an event in the loop that constructs the Calendar:

```
dates_of_calendar.each do |date|
  if @events[date.to_s].present?
    # well, there is an event happening for this date! treat it as your wishes!
  end
  # etc...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Would the enumberable detect method work? http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect

So as your looping through your condition could be...

```
semesters.detect{|s| s.begin_date > cal_begin_date ... //more conditions here} && 
exams.detect{|e| e.begin_date > cal_begin_date ... //more conditions here}
```